# What HTML element(s) to use to organize the page?

Tags: html, layout

I have search page that contains 4 groups of elements:

- The field where user types the keyword (event name)
- The filters such as dates (from/to), city, place
- The category filters (check boxes): concert, theater, musical, show and so on
- Top 20 events

Plus "Search" button.

So, I'm trying to figure out the right way to organize the page. Is it better to use "div" or "section" or something else and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this nice text in the [w3-documentation](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-section-element):

> The section element is not a generic container element. When an
> element is needed only for styling purposes or as a convenience for
> scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A
> general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the
> element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's
> outline.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I know that recommendation, but I'm not sure what does this mean "if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline".

Comment: I think outline here means something like table of contents. Perhaps the `<section>` tag is more useful, if the page is a "document" like an ebook.

Comment: I've also found an explanation in an article where the author claims to use the new tags `<article>`, `<section>` etc. over `<div>` for a better semantic understanding. So that `<div>`-tags shouldn't be used anymore. This needs further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you. if you want to stick with HTML5 Standards then Use scetion, etc. or your not wrong when use divs creating layouts

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: i preferred DIV for your scenario

Comment: Actually, I've read about HTML5's "section" tag, which is semantic tag, but I'm not sure if it fits in this case because it seems to me it's not up to semantic, but more to layout.